How to remove escape characters in K6 js
I'm trying make a POST request using K6. I'm fetching the request body from a APIs.json file in my script.js. When I try to use the request body in script.js file it now consists of escape characters. How do I get rid of them? I tried JSON.parse and JSON.stringify, but did not work.
APIS.json:
{
    "apiRequests":
    [
        {
            "requestVerb" : "POST",
            "requestHeaders" : [{"Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":"Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"}],
            "requestEndpoint" : "/individual",
            "apiName": "management-4",
            "target": "target1",
            "responseVariables": ["id","name"],
            "responseHeaders": [""],
            "requestBody": {"title":"Mr","givenName":"Rohit","familyName":"Reddy"}
        }
    ]
}

script.js
// To perform testing
import http from 'k6/http'
// To import API requests file
// import { open } from 'k6/fs';

const host = __ENV.HOST;
console.log(`Testing host = ${host}`);

// Ignore certificates
export const options = {
    insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
};

// GET API Requests
let apiRequests = JSON.parse(open('./APIs.json'));
console.log(`log = ${apiRequests}`);

apiRequests = JSON.stringify(apiRequests);
console.log(`Stringify = ${apiRequests}`);


// K6 Main function
export default function() {
    let httpVerb = "get";
    http[httpVerb](`https://${host}/health/v1/health`);
}

 Output:
time="2024-11-11T08:09:31Z" level=info msg="log = [object Object]" source=console
time="2024-11-11T08:09:31Z" level=info msg="Stringify = {\"apiRequests\":[{\"requestVerb\":\"POST\",\"requestHeaders\":[{\"Content-Type\":\"application/json\",\"Authorization\":\"***"}],\"requestEndpoint\":\"/individual\",\"apiName\":\"management-4\",\"target\":\"target1\",\"responseVariables\":[\"id\",\"name\"],\"responseHeaders\":[\"\"],\"requestBody\":{\"title\":\"Mr\",\"givenName\":\"Rohit\",\"familyName\":\"Reddy\"}}]}" source=console

Expected output:
time="2024-11-11T08:09:31Z" level=info msg="log = [object Object]" source=console
time="2024-11-11T08:09:31Z" level=info msg="Stringify = {"apiRequests":[{"requestVerb":"POST","requestHeaders":[{"Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":"***"}],"requestEndpoint":"/individual","apiName":"management-4","target":"target1","responseVariables":["id","name"],"responseHeaders":[""],"requestBody":{"title":"Mr","givenName":"Rohit","familyName":"Reddy"}}]}" source=console


You used JSON.parse and then JSON.stringify. I think this may cause escaped characters. Try using only JSON.parse to see if it works?

Output of JSON.parse is log = [object Object] not the request body I'm expecting.

But your msg property is itself enclosed in double quotes.  Do you see how msg="Stringify = {" would end right there after the { unless you escape the quotes within the stringify value?

@James, I got your point. What do you suggest me to do? If I send requestBody with {"title":... My request will fail with 400 Bad Request.

What exactly is the problem? Your request or your log format? The log format must escape the quotes so that it can be parsed again. You are not doing anything with your parsed JSON (your request does not send a payload). If you were sending a payload, I would assume that you need to build the actual request from your apiRequests object (and then only send apiRequests[0].requestBody as payload).

@knittl, currently, I'm only trying to only extract and log "requestBody" from APIs.json file. When I'm able to successfully extract it without any additional characters, I'll use use it in my http request. Yes, I intend use apiRequests[0].requestBody in my code. How can I achieve it?

@ReddyRohit I would need to see how you'd actually want to use the value. It should be as simple as const body = jsonParse(open('./API.json')).apiRequests[0].requestBody; doSomethingWithBody(body);

Idea is to construct an http request based on the values provided in APIs.json file. - In the array, I will create multiple objects. Each object will be used to construct one http request. To begin with, my first object is being used to construct a POST request. Here, I'm failing to fetch requestBody value from the object without escape characters. Output of  const body = JSON.parse(open('./API.json')).apiRequests[0].requestBody; doSomethingWithBody(body); is body = [object Object]

@ReddyRohit [object Object] is the string representation of a JavaScript object. If you use JSON.stringify, you'll get the JSON string representation. http.post('url', JSON.stringify(body), params) to send the request. I think you are confusing representation with the actual data/value.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Don't confuse represantation of data with actual data. I'm not sure which kind of output you show, but if you use console.log with JSON data in a local k6 script, there won't be any escaped characters:
export default function() {
  console.log(JSON.stringify({"key":"value"}));
}

Simply prints:
INFO[0000] {"key":"value"}                               source=console

Same with your given example code. For instance, you might create a request from your JSON with the following code:
import http from 'k6/http';

const json = {
    "apiRequests":
    [
        {
            "requestVerb" : "POST",
            "requestHeaders" : [{"Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":"Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"}],
            "requestEndpoint" : "/individual",
            "apiName": "management-4",
            "target": "target1",
            "responseVariables": ["id","name"],
            "responseHeaders": [""],
            "requestBody": {"title":"Mr","givenName":"Rohit","familyName":"Reddy"}
        }
    ]
};

export default function() {
  for (const apiRequest of json.apiRequests) {
    http[apiRequest.requestVerb.toLowerCase()](
        apiRequest.requestEndpoint,
        JSON.stringify(requestBody),
        {
          headers: apiRequest.requestHeaders[0],
          tags: {
            apiName: apiRequest.apiName,
            target: apiRequest.target,
          },
        },
    );
  }
}

